# Parsing a CAML query in C#

Tags: development, caml-query, regex

I have a SharePoint 2010 solution with a custom web part. I am using C# in Visual Studio 2012. The user has selected a view from a list, which I am storing as an SPView object, mobjView. I want to replace the < OrderBy > portion with new code, but preserve the < Where > portion, so my question involves the best way to parse the CAML string. This is what I have, I couldn't get Regex to cooperate, so I am wondering if there is a simpler way to parse the string (Where clause shortened to '...' for clarity).

```
// old string "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy><Where>...</Where>" 
string strQuery = mobjView.Query.Substring(mobjView.Query.IndexOf("<Where>"))
strQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='MyField' /></OrderBy>" + strQuery;
// new string  "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='MyField' /></OrderBy><Where>...</Where>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `XmlReader` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

or the `XmlDocument` class (my preference): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You'd do something like:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(mobjView.Query);
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("OrderBy"); 

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) // nodelist should only contain the single OrderBy clause
{
    node.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='MyField' />";
}
mobjView.Query = doc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's a lot more complicated than a string substitution.